# Heatmap in AnyChart not showing all Y values

Tags: javascript, django-templates, anychart

I'm trying to show heatmap in Django templates using AnyChart and I'm stuck with problem when not all Y values are shown in heatmap.

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, 3 out of 6 values are missing.

Here is code from the template:

```
...
<span>Mapped Dimensions</span>
<div id="mapped_dimensions_chart"></div>
<script>
    anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
        chart = anychart.heatMap({{ map_dimensions_data_anychart | safe }});
        var customColorScale = anychart.scales.linearColor();
        customColorScale.colors(["#CF7A78", "#E69645", "#69A231", "#4D7623"]);
        chart.colorScale(customColorScale);
        chart.container("mapped_dimensions_chart");
        chart.draw();
    });
</script>
...
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart tends to avoid overlapping labels of the yAxis so it hides some of them. You can disable this behavior and force the chart to show all labels. To achieve that, add the following line to your code:

```
chart.yAxis().overlapMode('allow-overlap');
```